# Error trapping help; Message keeps repeating

Tags: java

Just a little confused as to what is happening here. The point of this error trap is, for example, the user inputs 3 numbers/letters instead of a 4 digit number. This error trap was designed loop the question until the user gets it right. However it instead loops the error message. Can anyone give some pointers as to what is going on?

```
JFrame Error = new JFrame ();

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the 4 digit resistor values:");

while (true){
  try{

    int numInput = Integer.parseInt (input);

    if (numInput >= 1000) {
    break;
    }
    else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");

  }
}
```

Comment: The line that asks for the input isn't inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move code for ask the input to the loop.

```
JFrame Error = new JFrame ();

String input = null;

while (true){
  try{

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the 4 digit resistor values:");
    int numInput = Integer.parseInt (input);

    if (numInput >= 1000) {
    break;
    }
    else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As JacobM mentioned, you need to ask for the input inside the while loop.  When the catch clause terminates, the next thing your code does will be the first thing in the while loop.

```
JFrame Error = new JFrame ();

while (true){
  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the 4 digit resistor values:");
  try{

    int numInput = Integer.parseInt (input);

    if (numInput >= 1000) {
    break;
    }
    else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask for a new value, *inside* the loop. change it to:

```
String input;

try {
    while (true){
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the 4 digit resistor values:");

        int numInput = Integer.parseInt (input);

        if (numInput >= 1000) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Error,"Invalid Input.");
}
```

Comment: How isn't a try-catch required? What if the user enters abcd (this type of input *was* addressed in the question)?

Comment: @chris  Oh, will fix this.